# How do I write intersection and union of a set in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I know I can use the attached image in Rmarkdown?. I know I can write S union F complement with `$S \bigcup\ F^{c}$`

How do I change that sign to an "intersection" and not "union.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\bigcap` or `\cap`, which gives the symbol for `intersection`

```
$S\bigcap F^c$
```